# I don't know what's wrong this LaTeX coding

Tags: errors

I just Installed `LaTeX` basic and only downloaded the packages in the coding; it is a coding for a Journal I wanted to its format. However, I keep getting error messages whenever I want to execute the coding.

Notice that I could execute into a PDF file using basic commands from LaTeX online manual. Here is the coding I am trying to execute.

The only package I could not find & install is `doublespace`.

Any insight? Thank you in advance.

```
% this shell was created by Guillaume R. Frechette % it is a modification of the Standard LaTex Article (Harvard) shell

\documentclass[11pt]{article} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% \usepackage{amsfonts} \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{harvard} \usepackage{float} \usepackage{endnotes} \usepackage{doublespace}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10} %TCIDATA{OutputFilter=LATEX.DLL} %TCIDATA{} %TCIDATA{Created=Mon Jun 10 12:02:11 2002} %TCIDATA{LastRevised=Mon Jun 10 12:48:41 2002} %TCIDATA{} %TCIDATA{} %TCIDATA{Language=American English} %TCIDATA{CSTFile=LaTeX article (bright).cst}

\setlength{\textwidth}{5.5in} \setlength{\textheight}{8in} \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5in} \setlength{\topmargin}{0in} \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1} \makeatletter \renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}{3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}{\centering\normalsize\bf}} \renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}{3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}{\normalsize\bf}} \renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@}{3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}{\raggedright\normalsize\underline}} \def\enoteformat{\raggedright \parindent=1.8em \leavevmode\llap{\hbox{$^{\@theenmark}$}}} \makeatother \renewcommand{\footnote}{\endnote} \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} \newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement} \newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm} \newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom} \newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case} \newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim} \newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion} \newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition} \newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture} \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary} \newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion} \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition} \newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example} \newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise} \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma} \newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation} \newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem} \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition} \newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark} \newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution} \newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary} \newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}} \input{tcilatex}

\begin{document}

\title{A Paper For a Journal of the APSA (don't forget to make it 12 words or less)} \author{Polly Scie} \date{} \maketitle

\pagebreak
%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{beginflushleft}{\begin{flushleft}} }% %BeginExpansion \begin{flushleft} %EndExpansion %TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{worddouble}{\setstretch{1.805}\small\normalsize} }% %BeginExpansion \setstretch{1.805}\small\normalsize %EndExpansion This second grey box [worddouble] is optional. SWP's double space and the spacing between characters is different from other standard word processors such as Word (SWP puts less words per page). Hence, if you are close to the 45 pages limit, you can leave the [worddouble] tex field which reduces the spacing between lines to have approximately the same number of words per page as Word. Otherwise just delete it. In either case however, delete this explanation.

%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{beginabstract}{\begin{abstract}}}% %BeginExpansion \begin{abstract}% %EndExpansion Type your abstract here. %TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{endabstract}{\end{abstract}}}% %BeginExpansion \end{abstract}% %EndExpansion \pagebreak

\section{Section}

This shell document provides a sample layout of an American Political Science Association article. It is based on the Standard LaTex Article (Harvard) shell. Replace the text in this shell with your own.

\subsection{Subsection}

Use the Section tag for major sections, the Subsection tag for subsections, and the Subsubsection tab for subsubsections. Notice that I have put a period after the Subsubsection below. You should always do this if you go to that level, it is required by the Style Manual. Do not go lower than subsubsection as the style manual does not give any guidance as to how those should look like.\footnote{% I need to test the footnotes to make sure they are raggedright as required by the style manual and not justified as in the standard latex article. I also need more text so I cover at least 2 lines.}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection.}

You can apply the logical markup tag \emph{Emphasized}.

You can apply the visual markup tags \textbf{Bold}, \textit{Italics}, \textrm{Roman}, \textsf{Sans Serif}, \textsl{Slanted}, \textsc{Small Caps}, and \texttt{Typewriter}.

You can apply the special, mathematics only, tags $\mathbb{BLACKBOARD}$ $% \mathbb{BOLD}$, $\mathcal{CALLIGRAPHIC}$, and $\mathfrak{fraktur}$. Note that blackboard bold and calligraphic are correct only when applied to uppercase letters A through Z.

You can apply the size tags {\tiny tiny}, {\scriptsize scriptsize}, {\footnotesize footnotesize}, {\small small}, {\normalsize normalsize}, {\large large}, {\Large Large}, {\LARGE LARGE}, {\huge huge} and {\Huge Huge}% .

\subsection{Lists}

You can create numbered, bulleted, and description lists using the tag popup at the bottom left of the screen.

\begin{enumerate} \item List item 1

\item List item 2 \end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize} \item Bullet item 1

\item Bullet item 2 \end{itemize}

\begin{description} \item[Description List] Each description list item has a term followed by the description of that term. Double click the term box to enter the term, or to change it.

\item[Bunyip] Mythical beast of Australian Aboriginal legends. \end{description}

\QTP{Body Math} This is a Body Math paragraph. Each time you press the Enter key, Scientific WorkPlace switches to mathematics mode. This is convenient for carrying out ``scratchpad'' computations.

\subsection{Theorem Environments}

The following theorem-like environments (in alphabetical order) are available in this style.

\begin{acknowledgement} This is an acknowledgement \end{acknowledgement}

\begin{algorithm} This is an algorithm \end{algorithm}

\begin{axiom} This is an axiom \end{axiom}

\begin{case} This is a case \end{case}

\begin{claim} This is a claim \end{claim}

\begin{conclusion} This is a conclusion \end{conclusion}

\begin{condition} This is a condition \end{condition}

\begin{conjecture} This is a conjecture \end{conjecture}

\begin{corollary} This is a corollary \end{corollary}

\begin{criterion} This is a criterion \end{criterion}

\begin{definition} This is a definition \end{definition}

\begin{example} This is an example \end{example}

\begin{exercise} This is an exercise \end{exercise}

\begin{lemma} This is a lemma \end{lemma}

\begin{proof} This is the proof of the lemma. \end{proof}

\begin{notation} This is notation \end{notation}

\begin{problem} This is a problem \end{problem}

\begin{proposition} This is a proposition \end{proposition}

\begin{remark} This is a remark \end{remark}

\begin{solution} This is a solution \end{solution}

\begin{summary} This is a summary \end{summary}

\begin{theorem} This is a theorem \end{theorem}

\begin{proof}[Proof of the Main Theorem] This is the proof. \end{proof}

\textbf{DO\ NOT\ DELETE THE\ ENDNOTES TEX\ FIELD (the grey box after this). This is what transforms the footnotes into endnotes as required by the Style Manual.} %TCIMACRO{% %\TeXButton{endnotes}{\newpage %\begingroup %\renewcommand{\enotesize}{\normalsize} %\theendnotes %\endgroup}}% %BeginExpansion \newpage \begingroup \renewcommand{\enotesize}{\normalsize} \theendnotes \endgroup% %EndExpansion \pagebreak

\bibliographystyle{kluwer} \bibliography{harvard}

Your bibliographical information should be in ..\TEXTsymbol{\backslash}TCITex% \TEXTsymbol{\backslash}bibtex\TEXTsymbol{\backslash}bib\TEXTsymbol{\backslash% }harvard.bib. You can modify the appearance of references by selecting Typeset/Options and Packages. Scroll down the Packages in Use, select harvard, click on Modify, then use Category and Options to make your choices. References which are not cited in the text should be inserted here, between the [BIBTEX] and [endflushleft] using the Bibliography Entry Only -- No Citation option.

%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{endflushleft}{\end{flushleft}}}% %BeginExpansion \end{flushleft}% %EndExpansion \pagebreak

%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{B}{\begin{table}[here] \centering}}% %BeginExpansion \begin{table}[here] \centering% %EndExpansion \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} \hline Your & tables & should \ come & here. & Each \ separated & by & pagebreaks. \ \hline Use & the & table4_3 \ \hline fragment & to & create \ \hline tables & and & replace \ \hline tbp & by & here \ \hline in & the & first \ \hline tex & field & [B]. \ \hline Or & just & copy \ \hline paste & this & (from \ \hline \lbrack B] & to & [E]). \ \hline \end{tabular} \caption{Table Caption\label{key}} %TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{E}{\end{table}}}% %BeginExpansion \end{table}% %EndExpansion \pagebreak

Then your figures should come last. Also each separated by a page break. Don't forget to specify here as the Floating Placement in the Frame tab of Graphic Properties.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have the file `tcilatex` which was inputed by `\input{}`?

Comment: the first error is `! LaTeX Error: No counter 'MaxMatrixCols' defined.` which means `amsmath` is not loaded did you intend to comment out teh first line (with multiple `%%%`) it ends `%%%% \usepackage{amsfonts} \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{harvard} \usepackage{float} \usepackage{endnotes} \usepackage{doublespace}`  so none of those packages are loaded

Comment: It looks like the tex file you're trying to edit and compile was originally created by Scientific Workplace -- SWP for short. (A long-defunct precursor of Scientific Workplace was T3, pronounced "T cubed".) SWP used to be (say, 10 or 15 years ago) a reasonably well regarded software platform, but they've stagnated recently. You -- or the person who wrote the document in SWP -- should save the file while in SWP via "Save as" -> "Portable LaTeX format". This should create a .tex file that should be reasonably easily compilable by other TeX distributions, such as TeXLive and MikTeX.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the journal site you downloaded this from? They shouldn't be providing LaTeX format like this. Perhaps you downloaded the wrong file?