# I get the following error: undefined control sequence

Tags: beamer

Edit: I now posted the code for the whole presentation, as the proposed solution solved my example but there seem to be other issues.

I have checked the other questions with a similar problem. However, the proposed solutions did not help to make the code run in my case.

The code  below produces this error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@doifinframe ...eamer@frameslide}\par \QTR 
                                                  {frametitle}{Quantitative ...
l.71 \end{frame}
                %
```

The error is located in line 71, i.e., `\end{frame}%`

Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[notes=show]{beamer}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
%TCIDATA{OutputFilter=LATEX.DLL}
%TCIDATA{Version=5.50.0.2960}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="SaveForMode" CONTENT="1">}
%TCIDATA{BibliographyScheme=Manual}
%TCIDATA{Created=Wednesday, August 20, 2008 16:56:46}
%TCIDATA{LastRevised=Monday, August 28, 2023 10:45:48}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="GraphicsSave" CONTENT="32">}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="DocumentShell" CONTENT="Other Documents\SW\Slides - Beamer">}
%TCIDATA{CSTFile=beamer.cst}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="PrintViewPercent" CONTENT="100">}

\newenvironment{stepenumerate}{\begin{enumerate}[<+->]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemize}{\begin{itemize}[<+->]}{\end{itemize} }
\newenvironment{stepenumeratewithalert}{\begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemizewithalert}{\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{itemize} }
\usetheme{Madrid}
%\input{tcilatex}
\begin{document}

\title[Growth and Climate]{CLIMATE AND INCOME DIFFERENCES}
\subtitle{Climate Change and \ Public Policy: A Preview on Part II}
\author[XYZ XYZ]{Prof. XYZ\textsl{XYZ} \\
%EndAName
University of XYZ, XYZ}
\institute{XYZ}
\date{August 2023}
\maketitle

\section{Preview}

%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{BeginFrame}{\begin{frame}}}%
%BeginExpansion

%EndExpansion

%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{BeginFrame}{\begin{frame}}}%
%BeginExpansion
\begin{frame}%
%EndExpansion

\frametitle{Lecture 1: Climate Change and the Economy}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{The climate}:

\begin{itemize}
\item emissions and carbon concentration

\item global warming and climate damages
\end{itemize}

\item \textbf{The economy:}

\begin{itemize}
\item production needs energy

\item (dirty) energy (fossil fuels) cause emissions
\end{itemize}

\item \textbf{Integrated equilibrium}:

\begin{itemize}
\item climate damages affect the economy

\item the economy affects the climate
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{Transition: Box Out}{\transboxout}}%
%BeginExpansion
\transboxout%
%EndExpansion
%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{EndFrame}{\end{frame}}}%
%BeginExpansion
\end{frame}%
%EndExpansion

%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{BeginFrame}{\begin{frame}}}%
%BeginExpansion
\begin{frame}%
%EndExpansion

\frametitle{Lecture 2: Optimal Policy}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Social optimum}:

\begin{itemize}
\item Need `net zero emissions' to avoid excessive warming

\item What's the right income-climate trade-off?
\end{itemize}

\item \textbf{Market equilibrium:}

\begin{itemize}
\item Externalities might lead to catastrophic results

\item Can markets achieve the social optimum?
\end{itemize}

\item \textbf{Public policy}:

\begin{itemize}
\item Optimal carbon tax and emissions trading

\item Innovation policy in Lecture 3
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{Transition: Box Out}{\transboxout}}%
%BeginExpansion
\transboxout%
%EndExpansion
%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{EndFrame}{\end{frame}}}%
%BeginExpansion
\end{frame}%
%EndExpansion

%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{BeginFrame}{\begin{frame}}}%
%BeginExpansion
\begin{frame}%
%EndExpansion

\frametitle{Lecture 3: Innovation}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Different types of innovation}:

\begin{itemize}
\item Energy augmenting technical change

\item Emissions reducing technical change
\end{itemize}

\item \textbf{Directed technical change:}

\begin{itemize}
\item Substituting green (renewable) for dirty energy
\end{itemize}

\item \textbf{Public policy}:

\begin{itemize}
\item Basic research, private R\&D subsidies, targeted policy

\item Can we get a better income-climate trade-off?
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{Transition: Box Out}{\transboxout}}%
%BeginExpansion
\transboxout%
%EndExpansion
%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{EndFrame}{\end{frame}}}%
%BeginExpansion
\end{frame}%
%EndExpansion

%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{BeginFrame}{\begin{frame}}}%
%BeginExpansion
\begin{frame}%
%EndExpansion

\frametitle{Lecture 4: Recycling and Exhaustible Ressources}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Exhaustible resources}:

\begin{itemize}
\item Depletion of natural resources, shifting to renewable resources
\end{itemize}

\item \textbf{The circular economy:}

\begin{itemize}
\item Production uses raw materials and recycled materials

\begin{itemize}
\item Materials =\TEXTsymbol{>} output/consumption =\TEXTsymbol{>} waste

\item Waste =\TEXTsymbol{>} recycling =\TEXTsymbol{>} new materials
\end{itemize}

\item Innovation and regulatory interventions can improve the process
\end{itemize}

\item \textbf{Benefits of recycling}:

\begin{itemize}
\item saves natural resource dependence

\item saves waste disposal costs

\item avoids environmental damages
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{Transition: Box Out}{\transboxout}}%
%BeginExpansion
\transboxout%
%EndExpansion
%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{EndFrame}{\end{frame}}}%
%BeginExpansion
\end{frame}%
%EndExpansion

%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{BeginFrame}{\begin{frame}}}%
%BeginExpansion
\begin{frame}%
%EndExpansion

\frametitle{Quantitative Modeling}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Code your own climate change model!}

\begin{itemize}
\item apply theory and check the empirical evidence

\item study climate dynamics and global warming

\item develop a quantitative model to study the\newline
climate economy trade-off

\item analyze macro and climate effects of policy intervention
\end{itemize}

\item \textbf{Further work}: in a Master thesis?

\begin{itemize}
\item Illustrations prepared in class, complete with Matlab code

\item Code your own climate change model!

\item Ideas for Master thesis work with various extensions
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{Transition: Box Out}{\transboxout}}%
%BeginExpansion
\transboxout%
%EndExpansion
%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{EndFrame}{\end{frame}}}%
%BeginExpansion
\end{frame}%
%EndExpansion



\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is the `\QTR` macro supposed to come from? It works if you use the beamer macro `\frametitle{Quantitative Modeling}` instead

Comment: `\QTR` is undefined. Usually the frame title with `beamer` is set using `\frametitle{Quantitative Modeling}`. So maybe this is what you want.

Comment: Unrelated, but the `show=notes` option is deprecated for ages, use `\setbeameroption{show notes}` instead. You also don't need `\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}`, beamer already loads them for you.

Comment: thanks for your help. It works now for the example I posted. However, I'll edit my post and add the whole presentation as it still breaks down.

Comment: @M.A. `\TEXTsymbol` is not a default latex command. You will either have to define it, load a package which defines it or remove it. If you look into the log file, you will see error messages like `! Undefined control sequence.`. The last macro in the following line will tell you which macro is undefined.

Comment: @M.A. And consider this comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460485/i-dont-know-whats-wrong-this-latex-coding#comment1158125_460485